# Algorithm: Giving some integers, combine them which the last digit is the same as first digit

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search

Here is the detail(I'm not native English speaker, so apologize if gets confused...):
Giving some integers A0,...,Ai,...,Aj,...(num of integers is less than 100000).

When the **last digit of Ai is the same as the first digit of Aj**, it could be connected.

**Ai can only connected integer which after Ai(like Ai+1...).**

I need to get the number of digits of the longest connected integer.
(As this integer, **its first digit is also the same as its last digit.**)

> For example, Giving input:
>
> 3    (nums of integers)
>
> 123 31 1232    (integers)
>
> It could be combine to 12331, 123311232 or 311232.
>
> However, only 12331 is "its first digit is also the same as its last
> digit.". So, the output is expected to be 5.

This was a question in my test last week, I was trying the codes below.
It did work... with a small data. However when system giving more data like 5000 integers, I failed by overtime(required in 6s).

Is there any to reduce the time(pruning) of this program? Or is there other idea to solve this problem?(Maybe dp? idk)

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
using ull = unsigned long long;

typedef struct integer{
    int first, last;
    int num;
}Integer;

ull N;
int front=-1, rare=-1;
Integer queue[100005];
Integer input[100005];
int result = 0;

int get_first_digit(ull n) {
    while(n>10) n /= 10;
    return n;
}

int get_last_digit(ull n) {
    return n % 10;
}

int get_num_digit(ull n) {
    int i;
    while(n>10) {
        n /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    return i+1;
}

bool is_abled_connect(int i) {
    if (rare == -1) return true;
    if (queue[rare].last == input[i].first) return true;
    return false;
}

void dfs(int next_num, int total) {
    if (queue[rare].last == queue[0].first && total > result) result = total;
    if (next_num == N) return;

    for (int i=next_num;i<N;i++) {
        if (is_abled_connect(next_num)) {
            queue[++rare] = input[i];
            total += input[i].num;
            dfs(i+1, total);
            rare--;
            total -= input[i].num;
        }
    }
    return;
}



int main() {
    cin >> N; // input the number of integers
    for (ull i=0;i<N;i++) {
        ull num;
        cin >> num; // input every interger
        input[i].first = get_first_digit(num);
        input[i].last = get_last_digit(num);
        input[i].num = get_num_digit(num);
    }
    dfs(0,0);
    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Don't use large arrays, use `std::vector` in C++.

Comment: In C++ you really don't need to use `typedef struct` as the `struct` part is optional. That's a C thing you can abandon. You should also kick the `using namespace std` habit, the `std::` prefix serves an important function, and avoid using quirky things like `using ull` as well. Just use `uint64_t` if you want something specific.

Comment: Dynamic programming over (position, lastDigit) -> length.

Comment: Can you explain which part of this programming task requires all numbers to be read, first, into an array, before working on them? A very careful read of the logic reveals no such requirement, whatsoever, the algorithm requires checking only two numbers at a time. The shown logic is fundamentally flawed, artificially limiting the maximum number of values. The correct algorithm only needs to read one number at a time, keeping track of the required data as each number gets read in. The shown code needs to be rewritten from scratch, using the correct algorithm.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sry that not describing it accurately. I haved edited the question. It gave an N as numbers of integers which is going to input. Then gave those integers. I used constant as array size because num of input integers is less than 100000.

Comment: Suggestion: read the number as **text**; then it's simple to get the first digit, the last digit, and the number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried with C# language and steps are briefly explained, you can go through the code and the explanation both.

**Explanation:**

> Lets take your example: [123, 31, 1232]

1. Iterate from index 0 till last, we are only concerned with first and last digits, So I converted the visited digit to string and Simply fetch values from index 0 and last(i.e length - 1).
2. Now we have 123 digit as string "123", now keep lookup(dictionary) for first digit, i.e add first digit(1) into the dictionary with reference of its index(save index value as value). **dictionary is nothing just a list of key-value pairs.**
3. We also need to process last digit, so check if last digit is already exists in the dictionary, if exists, fetch that value and using the index saved into the fetched value you can simply calculate the count.
4. To calculate the count, when visiting the next digit you have to maintain the length of each digit so that you can count and save the value easily.

---

> **steps followed in the code:**
> [image: How the code works: refer attached image]

> **Code sample:**

```
    public static int calculate(List<int> numbers)
    {
        int max = 0;
        Dictionary<int, int> StrtValDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        Dictionary<int, int> CountDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for(int i=0; i< numbers.Count;i++)
        {
            string digit = Math.Abs(numbers[i]).ToString();
            int len = digit.Length-1;
            int FirstDigit = int.Parse(digit[0].ToString());
            int LastDigit = int.Parse(digit[digit.Length-1].ToString());
            CountDict.Add(i, digit.Length);
            if(StrtValDict.ContainsKey(FirstDigit) == false)
            {
                StrtValDict.Add(FirstDigit, i);
            }
            if(StrtValDict.ContainsKey(LastDigit))
            {
                int pos = StrtValDict[LastDigit];
                int count = GetCount(CountDict, pos, i);
                if(count > max)
                    max = count;
            }


        }


        return max;
    }


    //when last digit found in the dictionary we are counting the digits between the indexes from this function
    private static int GetCount(Dictionary<int, int> countDict, int pos, int i)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j=pos; j<=i; j++)
        {
            count += countDict[j];
        }
        return count;
    }
```

> Note, using dictionaries, get the value and add the value having the time complexity of only O(1) and I have used string type casting to avoid division by 10 again and again to get first and last digits, as single integer can go up to 5-6 digits possibly.

*Hopefully this way could help you out.
All the best and happy coding!!!*

Comment: A dictionary is a little overkill for 10 items, right? A perfect-hash bit-vector would be even faster?

Comment: I'm really appreciate helping me. But the codes above seems that GetCount function are counting all numbers from first time meet the digit(which is same as last digit).
For example, input 7 numbers, 32, 123, 321, 1151, 7788, 9988, 1883. It will give 24 as result but expect 11 (32111511883).
Although, I think I will trying to continue to figure it out. ty u again.